# Kähler structure in $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I am trying to some computations about the Kähler structure of $(S^2,\omega, J)$, where $\omega_x(u,v)=\langle x,u\times v\rangle $ and $J_x(u)=x\times u$. First I have tried to check that if we have $\phi:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ to be the stereographic projection we will have that $\phi^*(\frac{4dx\wedge dy}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2})$, but I think I have gotten a sign wrong but I can't find my mistake.

Recall that in cylindrical coordinates $\omega$ is given by $d\theta \wedge dz$. Also in cylindrical coordinates the local representation of the stereographic projection is $(\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\cos(\theta)}{1-z},\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sin(\theta)}{1-z})$.Now we will have that

$\phi^* \tau = \frac{4d(\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\cos(\theta)}{1-z})\wedge d(\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sin(\theta)}{1-z})}{((\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\cos(\theta)}{1-z})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sin(\theta)}{1-z})^2+1)^2}$

Now notice that
$d(\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\cos(\theta)}{1-z})=-\sin(\theta)\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1-z}d\theta+\frac{\cos(\theta)}{(1-z)\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz=d(\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sin(\theta)}{1-z})=\cos(\theta)\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1-z}d\theta+\frac{\sin(\theta)}{(1-z)\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz$

And so we get that

$d(\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\cos(\theta)}{1-z})\wedge d(\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sin(\theta)}{1-z})=\frac{\cos(\theta)^2}{(1-z)^2}dz\wedge d\theta+\frac{\sin(\theta)^2}{(1-z)^2}dz\wedge d\theta= \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}dz\wedge d\theta$.
Note also that
$((\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\cos(\theta)}{1-z})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sin(\theta)}{1-z})^2+1)^2= (\frac{(1-z^2)}{(1-z)^2}+1)^2=\frac{4}{(1-z)^2}$

If anyone can spot a mistake I would appreciate it, since I think there should be a mignus sign somewhere.

The other thing is that I am not understanding is how can I actually represent $J$ in local coordinates, say for example in cyclindrical ones? I think I need to use $d\phi$ and it's inverse but this would lead to alot of computations, and so I am wondering if there is an easier way to see it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not follow you at all. Stereographic projection maps to $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Yeah you are right , I have fixed it . @TedShifrin

Comment: It's not clear to me what your goal is with these calculations. What assumption are you starting with, and what conclusion do you want to derive?

Comment: I would like to see that $\phi^* \tau = \omega$, and try to understand what $J$ is in local coordinates.

Comment: I don't see your original formula for $\tau$. And do you have a formula for $\omega$ that you're aiming for?

Comment: $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$ I suggest avoiding cylindrical coordinates and, if $\phi(u,v,w) = z$, finding the formula for $z$ in terms of $u, v, w$. From the formula for the spherical metric in stereographic coordinates, it is easy to see what the Kahler form of $S^2$ is on the image of $\phi$. you can then pull that back to $S^2$ using $\phi$. But the formula for $\omega$ in terms of $u,v,w$ will not be unique. The complex structure on $\C$ is rotation counterclockwise by 90 degrees. If you pull this back to $S^2$, you get rotation by 90 degrees in each tangent space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be easier to pull back $\omega$ by $\phi^{-1}$, but just write $\tau$ in polar coordinates to start with, and this won't be bad at all. In particular,
$$\phi(z,\theta) = R(\cos\theta,\sin\theta), \quad\text{with}\quad R=\sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}.$$
Write $R^2 = \dfrac{1+z}{1-z}$, and so $R\,dR = \dfrac{dz}{(1-z)^2}$.
Thus,
$$\phi^*\tau = \phi^*\left(\frac{4R\,dR\wedge d\theta}{(1+R^2)^2}\right) = \frac{4\,dz/(1-z)^2}{(2/(1-z))^2}\wedge d\theta = dz\wedge d\theta,$$
as required.